# Why does the helm operation pod pull the wrong image?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I am installing the rancher chart with helm and there is a section in the values.yaml of that chart that you could specify the default registry:

`systemDefaultRegistry:`

So when I specified a registry for example `systemDefaultRegistry: mydefaultregistry.com` and install the chart, I can see that the images are being pulled from this registry. BUT say I remove that registry and leave it blank `systemDefaultRegistry:` and then install the chart again, it will continue to use that first registry although I didn't specify one.

This behavior will continue to happen each time I actually specify a registry. See trend below:

`systemDefaultRegistry: mydefaultregistry.com`
-Uses the mydefaultregistry.com

`systemDefaultRegistry:` #Leaves Blank
-Uses the mydefaultregistry.com

`systemDefaultRegistry: apple-registry.com`
-Uses apple-registry.com

`systemDefaultRegistry:` #Leaves Blank
-Uses apple-registry.com

Leaving blank will cache and use the previous registry every time.

I have tried to comment that option out and remove it all together. I expect for the helm operations image to not use a old registry that is not in the values.yaml file. I thought if I didn't add anything in that option, it would result to a default rancher registry maybe?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What part of the Helm template code that you've written uses the `systemDefaultRegistry:` setting?  If you're just trying to deploy an existing third-party chart, this doesn't seem like a programming-related question, and another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah you might be right. This is in regard to a 3rd party rancher chart that this value is mentioned.